# Display image with node from mongodb gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

the code below does work in firefox, but not in IE / Chrome, where the node app crashes with message "metadata unknown".

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongo =  require('mongodb') ,
    qs =  require('qs') ,
    mongoServer = mongo.Server, 
    Db = mongo.Db,
    Grid = require('gridfs-stream'),
    fs = require('fs'); 

var server = new mongoServer('127.0.0.1', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
var DB = new Db('my_sitebase_image', server,{safe:true});
DB.open(function(err,db){db.admin().authenticate('ident','passwd',function(err,result){}) }); 

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri); 
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
var image = query.image;
var gfs = Grid(DB, mongo);
//
gfs.files.findOne({ filename: query.image },function (err, file) {   
    if(file!=null){
        lastModified = file.uploadDate; 
                    // put logic here to cache to disk.
        mimeType = file.metadata.contentType; 
        //
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});   
        //
        readstream = gfs.createReadStream({filename: query.image });
        readstream.pipe(res);  

    }else{ 
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('404 Not Found\n');
        res.end();
    }

})    
}).listen(1337);
```

The goal is to change my php/mongo code.
I'm thinking ( as i type ) of a favicon problem or something like that...
For the moment, i do not succeed.

Many thanks.

edit : i've added favicon test, nothing changes :

```
var countF = 0;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    countF += 1;
    console.log(countF); // IE and Chrome don't log nothin here
    if (req.url == '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-type' : 'text/plain'});
        res.end('not found'); 

}else{   // ...
```

Comment: Could it be Chrome is requesting multiple files at once? You're using a bunch of global variables which will get overwritten with each new request, so expect undefined behaviour...

Comment: Yes, i removed the global var on gfs, and this now works.

        var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query; 
      gfs = Grid(DB, mongo);
      //
      gfs.files.findOne({ filename: query.image },function (err, file) {

Comment: given the problem manifests in one browser but not another, wouldn't tagging it with browser related keywords be more effective in getting knowledgable eyes on it?

Comment: @kamsky : yes, but how modify ?